# How can I ouput a string with qoutes with a 'for' loop printing the index and given string in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to print out a string containing double quotes after appending multiple items in a *for* loop. However, they currently disappear.

```
def print_five(word):
    for i in range(1, 6):
        print(f"{i}{word}", end=" ")

print_five("rock")
```

This is the output right now:

```
1rock 2rock 3rock 4rock 5rock
```

However..., this the desired output:

```
"1rock 2rock 3rock 4rock 5rock "
```

Comment: I suspect you have misunderstood the assignment.  They are using the quote marks to show you what output to provide but they don't want them in the output.

Comment: That's what I thought too but it's not passing the test.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Use backslash to escape the characters.

```
def print_five(word):
    five_word = f"1{word}"
    for i in range(2, 6):
         five_word = five_word + f" {i}{word}"

    print(f"\"{five_word} \"")
```

A more elegant solution similar to the one that seems to have been deleted. Note that when working with strings that are supposed to contain double-quotes, it makes sense to work with [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) using single quotes:

```
def print_five(word):
    print(f'"{" ".join([f"{i}{word}" for i in list(range(1, 6))])} "')

print_five("rock")
# "1rock 2rock 3rock 4rock 5rock "
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me why use five_word = f"1{word}"?

Comment: It's the easiest to understand. Someone else had posted another answer but I think they did not have the double quotes. Anyway, apparently they deleted it. I edited my answer to show their solution, too. It was a little more elegant.